# How to version SignalR websockets?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client

We are building a web application in Asp.Net Core that will be used to centralize and communicate with a lot of instances of a custom servers(which is in C# too).

We need versionning, because updating those custom servers is really time consuming and can be a blocker for people to install newer version of the web app.

For the HTTP part, it's "easy", we have to use the Asp.Net Core versionning and a given version of the custom server will know how to communicate with a given version of the web app.

But we have a SignalR service that is used to provide notification to the custom servers from the web app, and request some data, some actions, ... Is there a way to provide several version of the client interface for this? And having the signalR server able to transform the message to each version?

Thank you

Comment: As described in official GitHub `"Versioning a hub is not supported out-of-the-box, but it could be made to work."` You could check further details in this [`official document`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/626#issuecomment-620664210)